# ошибка с Heroku

Tags: java, git, cmd, heroku

Пытаюсь выставить приложение на сервер heroku, но не получается, делаю всё как по инструкции:

> Install the Heroku CLI Download and install the Heroku CLI.
>
> If you haven't already, log in to your Heroku account and follow the
>   prompts to create a new SSH public key.
>
> `$ heroku login` Create a new Git repository Initialize a git
>   repository in a new or existing directory
>
> `$cd my-project/` `$ git init` `$ heroku git:remote -a name` Deploy your
>   application Commit your code to the repository and deploy it to Heroku
>   using Git.
>
> `$ git add .` `$ git commit -am "make it better"` 
>     `$ git push heroku > master`
>
> Existing Git repository For existing repositories, simply add
>   the heroku remote
>      `$ heroku git:remote -a name`

После ввода команды

```
$ git push heroku master
```

Выходит ошибка

> 'c:\Games\discord>git push heroku master    Counting objects: 323,
>   done.
>
> ```
> Compressing objects: 100% (312/312), done.
> Writing objects: 100% (323/323), 360.29 KiB | 922.00 KiB/s, done.
> Total 323 (delta 31), reused 0 (delta 0)
> remote: Compressing source files... done.
> remote: Building source:
> remote:
> remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
> remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect 
> the
> buildpack to use for this application automatically.
> remote:                         See 
> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildp
> acks
> remote:
> remote:  !     Push failed
> remote: Verifying deploy...
> remote:
> remote: !       Push rejected to name.
> remote:
> To https://git.heroku.com/name.git
> ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/boiling-cliffs-58356.git'
> ```

Красным подчеркнута только ошибка что ниже

> [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
>    error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https://git.heroku.com/boiling-cliffs-58356.git'

Пытался делать pull перед push как советовал гугл,но это не особо помогло И если поможет,то на сайте https://git.heroku.com/boiling-cliffs-58356.git только надпись Method Not Allowed

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том, что у вас репозиторий пустой, поэтому heroku не может определить что делать с тем, что вы запушили.
Попробуйте для начала создать простой maven или gradle проект. По ссылке есть хорошая [документация](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-gradle-on-heroku)